# Как писать программный код используя кирилицу вместе с привычной латиницей? С++

Tags: c++, кириллица, clion

появилось желание написать код где некоторые привычные методы и имена можно писать на украинском языке, по факту меняю все украинские і на английские i , так-что основной вопрос в добавлении остальной кириллицы.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
using число= int;
using нецiлеЧисло = double;
using безВозврату = void;
#define публiчне public
#define клас  class
#define корень  sqrt
#define степiнь  pow
#define сiнус  sin
#define возврат  return
#define вивiд  cout
#define ввiд  cin
#define мова setlocale


число z1();

клас A {
публiчне:
    нецiлеЧисло a;
    нецiлеЧисло b;
    нецiлеЧисло x;
    нецiлеЧисло rez;

    безВозврату розрахувати() {
        rez = корень(x * x + b) - (b * b * степiнь(сiнус(x + a), 3));
    }
};
```

Вот пример который я сделал, но среда разработки ругается
Попробовал поискать на просторах интернета - ничего не нашел
Пробовал менять кодировки файлов, так чтоб все символы в них присутствовали, ничего не получилось
Использую среду Clion

Comment: А может не надо?))

Comment: є ж вже 1С такий

Comment: @VladimirGonchar , ну уж хочется очень так сделать чисто в качестве эксперимента именно в С++ ибо на самом деле сдаю очень простые лабы в универе, хочется хоть что-то новое попробовать)

Comment: "синус"/"корінь"... і купа інших дивних слів.. Хочется взять и подарить словарик, а потом ещё один.

Comment: @KoVadim не очень понял что вы имеете ввиду, я же написал что цель данного обсуждения - разобраться как заменить те же привычные sin та sqrt на украинские аналоги синус та корінь

Comment: Проверил, clang 7 нормально собирает. Его можно к clion прикрутить.

Comment: @Pronnik я о том, что украинские переводы "безграмотны" и я испытываю испанский стыд. Код будет работать, если сохранять в utf-8. gcc не любит такое, clang - соберет без проблем. Студия тоже должна собрать

Comment: Если в VC++, то сохраняем всю хрень в utf-8, а потом компилируем с ключиком `/utf-8`. Так ваш код компилируется... Только вот вызывает полное ощущение какого-то, скажем так, очень зеленого новичка. Как пришедших из паскаля не очень опытных программистов выдает желание начать писать `#define begin {` и иже с ними :) Я вообще считаю, что это наше счастье - что языки программирования не похожи на родные; все эти `если x==5 то` были бы сущим мучением...

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan благодарю)
Нельзя отмечать несколько пользователей в комментарии, спасибо так-же KoVadim и Harry